# ASP.NET working with multiple web.configs

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

IIS structure

```
   MyWebsite     
   ..
   ..
   applications\  <--folder
       \website1  <--web 1 contains its web.config file
       \website2  <--web 2 contains its web.config file
   ..
   bin\  <- contains both the dlls ABC.abc and DEF.def 
   web.config
```

The root web.config contains

```
   <namespaces> 
     <add namespace="ABC.abc" />
     <add namespace="DEF.def" />
   </namespaces>
```

when root website loads it works fine. But when loading website1\website2 it complains

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ABC' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It works if I add the two dlls to bin folder of website1 and website2, But I dont want to copy those dlls to all my projects.

Is it possible to not load root web.config file when loading website1 project , only use the web.config from website 1 project? or another way to skip loading the dlls (ABC.abc) when loading website1 application?

Comment: What kind of "folder" is "application"? Learn to use the accurate terms, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chrad/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools so that others can understand you easily (or even a screen shot can save a thousand words).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a proper way to deploy two projects as a folder under your website. It could cause configuration conflict. Now that you are going to host website1/2 under your website, then you should deploy them as application and you have to copy dll to both website1 and website2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/

If you don't want to copy these dll to all projects. Then you could try to integrate two project to one project. Of course, you could register your dlls to GAC Or use  `<probing>`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best practice is adding application under website if you are using IIS Deployment 
just Right click on Websites and add Applications
it should work

but in your case i think you might be using any providers shared site

here what you can do is

**MAIN==>** your main site should not be a server side website and must be a static website with Html  and(Javascript)

**Main2**=>will be a virtual path inside the website with Your current Main Application with Web.Config

**Sub 1**=>  Sub 1 will be a virtual path inside the website it will contain your server side app1  with Web.Config

**Sub 2**=> will be a virtual path inside the website Containing your server side app2 with Web.Config

you can use the MAIN to redirect to Sub1 and Sub2 by following way

Query Param 
 **Say ur website path is www.x.com
now what you need is in your MAIN static site write a script that will read Query Params
now if Queryparam is null or no val then Redirect to Main2 Virtual Site.
if Queryparam is say app1 then  Redirect to Sub1 Virtual Site.
if Queryparam is app2  Redirect to app2 Virtual Site.**

at the end you linnk may look something like this

**1. www.x.com 
 2. www.x.com?app=app1
 3. www.x.com?app=app2**